# Python gRPC server does not listen on specified port

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, grpc, grpc-python

I'm trying to make a gRPC python server-client application following [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/helloworld/greeter_server.py) but I can't put the server on my code on a listening state. After adding the code almost as exactly equals to the example and running the `start` method yet nothing is listening on the port specified. My code is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import grpc
import interface_pb2
import interface_pb2_grpc
from concurrent import futures
import time
# some other imports...

class GrpcInterface(interface_pb2_grpc.ManipulaMapaServicer):
    def CriaItem(self, request, context):
        # do stuff...

    def LeItem(self, request, context):
        # do stuff...

    def AtualizaItem(self, request, context):
        # do stuff...

    def DeletaItem(self, request, context):
        # do stuff...

_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS = 60 * 60 * 24

def main():
    server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10))
    interface_pb2_grpc.add_ManipulaMapaServicer_to_server(GrpcInterface(), server)
    print('Vai iniciar o servidor gRPC na porta ' + str(8888))
    server.add_insecure_port('[::]:' + str(8888))
    server.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(_ONE_DAY_IN_SECONDS)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        server.stop(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        main()
    except Exception as e:
        print('Erro ao rodar servidor: ')
        print(str(e))
```

The code for `interface_pb2_grpc.ManipulaMapaServicer` are of course auto generated (with the command `python3 -m grpc_tools.protoc -I . --python_out=. --grpc_python_out=. interface.proto`) based on my `interface.proto`:

```
syntax = "proto3";

message msgItem {
    int64 chave = 1;
    string valor = 2;
}

message status {
    string resposta = 1; 
    msgItem itemResposta = 2; 
}

service ManipulaMapa {
    rpc CriaItem (msgItem) returns (status) {}
    rpc LeItem (msgItem) returns (msgItem) {}
    rpc AtualizaItem (msgItem) returns (status) {}
    rpc DeletaItem (msgItem) returns (status) {}
}
```

The execution reaches the `while True:` loop inside `main` yet no server running on port `8888`. What can be wrong here? By the way, this question is not duplicate from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43379788/python-grpc-server-not-starting) one because in this last question the problem was caused by a garbage collector that ran right after the `start` method.

Comment: What OS are you running this on?

Comment: On Devuan Linux

Comment: I have started a VM and tried out your script and it is working. Of course, it is  a basic install. Maybe, you could try to use a higher port number? How did you try to connect to it? `nc`? Are you trying from the same machine or is it on another host?

Comment: I'm not trying to connect to it because it is not listening. If I run `netstat -tulpn` it doesn't appear there

Comment: Are you getting any error whilst invoking server? Also, could you try strace command whilst invoking server and share the traceback?

Cheers, Dheeraj

Answer (score 0):

You can try to enable logging before calling main().
If there is anything wrong during the server.start() calling, it will write error logs.

That is, add this before main().

```py
logging.basicConfig()
```

For instance, if the port is already listening by other processes.

```
E0830 19:35:33.731000000 55600 src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/insecure/server_chttp2.cc:40] {"created":"@1567164933.731000000","description":"No address added out of total 1 resolved","file":"src/core/ext/transport/chttp2/server/chttp2_server.cc","file_line":394,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1567164933.731000000","description":"Failed to add port to server","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_windows.cc","file_line":510,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1567164933.731000000","description":"OS Error","file":"src/core/lib/iomgr/tcp_server_windows.cc","file_line":201,"os_error":"Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.\r\n","syscall":"bind","wsa_error":10048}]}]}
```